# get action bar/nav bar in dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I trying to get popup with tab bar/action bar but I am getting dialog and tab bar behind the dialog .How do I get the tab bar within dialog? I really appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TabListener {

      final String[] page_titles = new String[]{"Home", "contact", "Apps"};
        //this will go the description TextView
            final String[] desc = new String[]{
                "This is the homepage ",
                "contact",
                "apps"
        };
    ViewPager pager;

    ActionBar bar;

    Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



           pager = (ViewPager)dialog. findViewById(R.id.pager);

          bar = getActionBar();

            myAdaptertest1 mAdapter = new myAdaptertest1(this);

            bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

            pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                    bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });



            Tab hometab = bar.newTab();
            hometab.setText("Home");
            hometab.setTabListener(this);
            bar.addTab(hometab);

            Tab cameratab = bar.newTab();
            cameratab.setText("contact");
            cameratab.setTabListener(this);
            bar.addTab(cameratab);

            Tab exploretab = bar.newTab();
            exploretab.setText("apps");
            exploretab.setTabListener(this);
            bar.addTab(exploretab);


            bar.show();
            bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); 
            bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);


            dialog.show();
    }


    private class myAdaptertest1 extends PagerAdapter{

        Context context;

        public myAdaptertest1(Context c){
            this.context = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              return page_titles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              return v.equals(o);
        }





        public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null, false);

            TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            TextView description = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);

            title.setText(page_titles[position]);
            description.setText(desc[position]);

            //This is very important
            ( (ViewPager) pager ).addView( vi, 0 );

            return vi;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View pager, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) pager).removeView((View) view);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public static void showAsPopup(Activity activity) {
        //To show activity as dialog and dim the background, you need to declare android:theme="@style/PopupTheme" on for the chosen activity on the manifest
        activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        LayoutParams params = activity.getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        params.width = 850; //fixed width
        params.alpha = 1.0f;
        params.dimAmount = 0.5f;
        activity.getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
    }

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you want your dialog to have an action bar? ... Is there any specific reason as to why?

Comment: yes exactly.Basically I am using sliding drawer and when I click on one of the options I need to open dialog with navigation tabs as above .so that when user presses back then the dialog disappears.Make sense? If the above is possible let me know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want are tabs (meaning you don't need the action bar in your dialog), try adding [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) and [TabWidget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html)s in a custom dialog layout. You should probably refrain from putting an actionbar in a dialog.

Comment: I want tab and swipe too.is that possible?

Comment: Swipe as in a ViewPager? Again... why is all of these needed in a dialog? When you click something in your sliding drawer, why don't you just change a fragment or something?

Comment: I am not using fragments anywhere I am using activity in the entire app.So is it possible to do that ? Also I have never used fragments till now so I dont know the behavior when compared to activity.

Comment: You should probably think over exactly what you want to do following some [Android patterns](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/index.html). Look over those guidelines and properly flesh out an app. What you sound like you're trying to accomplish doesn't sound very satisfactory.